# how to stop delayed job to execute duplicate records

Tags: delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-2

```
  counter.times do
              count_var+= 1
              range1 = process_limit * count_var
              sms = Delayed::Job.enqueue(SmsManager.new(arr_msg_array[i1...range1], recipients[i1...range1], student_type[i1...range1], reciver_type[i1...range1], reciver_id[i1...range1], created_by[i1...range1])) i1= range1
            end


----------   


 class SmsManager
  attr_accessor :recipients, :message, :astudent_type, :areciver_type, :areciver_id, :acreated_by
```

def initialize(message, recipients, student_type, caregiver_type, receiver_id, created_by)
end

```
      def perform
          begin
            recipients.each_with_index do |recipient,i|                
            end
              end
            end
            end
```

Answer (score 1):

On every failure job , delayed handler tries to re execute the whole array of jobs as per the number of  defined reattempts.